# Meaning of "What's in it for (someone)?"

Tags: idiom-meaning

On another SE site, I wrote in a comment

> What's in it for X?

(X is a person.)  I was asked what this phrase meant.  I looked in three online dictionaries of idioms and couldn't find it.  It showed up in the urban dictionary as an acronym but I would think a more formal dictionary should have it buried somewhere.

To me, this phrase was a less blunt way of saying

> What would X gain from doing your grunt work for you?

I'm looking for a documented definition and usage notes.

(I don't think it's necessary to wade through the question on the other site in order to understand and answer this question.)

Comment: "What's in it for X?" is not always as negative as your example, it could be phrased as a genuine question.  But it is interesting that "What's in it for" doesn't seem to appear in any online reference.

Comment: It is a common saying in BrE. What's in it for me ? has a very definite meaning of requiring a reward for effort of any kind. The [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=in+it+for+me&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cin%20it%20for%20me%3B%2Cc0) of 'in it for me' may (or may not) reflect the usage of the whole sentence.

Comment: Please add your research. Even if the research has not proved fruitful, listing (and linking to) the sources you've checked in help others check and/or avoid duplicating grunt work. / Questions not accompanied by reasonable research (fruitful or not) including  attributions and links may be closed.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - Okay, in future I will list the three I tried.  But I wonder if in this case GEdgar would then have skipped the dictionary I tried.  He found the phrase by looking with a different pronoun.  (Which shows a limitation of that search feature, I suppose.)

Comment: A Google search for << "what's in it for" + meaning >>" gives the McGraw-Hill Dictionary of American Idioms and Phrasal Verbs article as the first hit. And you say you tried OED? Do you mean ODO?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - Sorry, I cited the wrong person.  I meant JeffUK not GEdgar. // I got tangled up with the quotation marks where you showed your search.  I can say that when I did my search what came up was a lot of urban dictionary, which I will use for modern slang that is not yet in a standard dictionary, which I thought should have this established idiom. // I see that for next time I should also document exactly how I did my search, so I can learn and improve my googling skills.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Free Online Dictionary's entry for [What's in it for me?](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/What%27s+in+it+for+me%3F):

> Inf. What is the benefit for me in this scheme? Bob: Now that plan is
>   just what is needed. Bill: What's in it for me? What do I get out of
>   it? Sue: We signed the Wilson contract yesterday. Mary: That's great!
>   What's in it for me?

Has a citation from the  "McGraw-Hill Dictionary of American Idioms and Phrasal Verbs. © 2002 by The McGraw-Hill Companies, Inc."  which might be your 'more formal' source.

Comment: That was one of the ones I looked in.  Funny that without the lucky choice of pronoun the search came up empty.  Anyway, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The OED has this definition... In the entry for **in**, definition number  IV 25 c .

> **in it:** an advantage (to be received from something). Usu. in phr. *what was (or is, etc.) in it for (someone).*

The earliest example they show is from 1965.

Comment: Wish I could give two checkmarks.  Both excellent answers, I'm just going by the timestamps.  Thank you.